# Is it possible to get network interface index not via /sys?

Tags: sysfs, network-interface, ioctl

So what I'm looking for is an interface index (or name) but the real one.
`if_nametoindex(3)` and `ioctl(2)` don't seem to help me here. Now the only way I found how to do this is via `/sys`. Let me demonstrate on example what I need:

```
# cat /sys/class/net/bond0.1007/ifindex 
26
# cat /sys/class/net/bond0.1007/iflink
23                                  <-- I need either this or a reference to bond0
# cat /sys/class/net/bond0/ifindex 
23
```

Is there a way to do it with a function call or the only way is `sysfs`?

Comment: Look at what `ip link show` does (probably using the netlink api)

Comment: See also `/proc/net/vlan/config` or `/proc/net/vlan/bond0.1007` if it's a vlan interface.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. I decided to keep using `/sys`. `/proc` or `/sys` are more or less the same in that sense. I just wanted to check if there is a syscall to get this kind of info, it turns out there is not.

Comment: the syscalls would be the sendmsg/recvmsg using the netlink socket API.

Comment: rtnetlink documentation: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html - issue `RTM_GETLINK` message and look for `IFLA_LINK` attribute in reply.

Comment: If you want to do using function call then check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264371/how-to-get-nic-details-from-a-c-program

Answer (score 4):

The command `ip link show` is probably what you want.  It will display the index in front of the interface information.  Example below from a system with bonded NICs.

```
# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9214 qdisc mq master bond0 portid 000f53000000 state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0f:53:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9214 qdisc mq master bond0 portid 000f53000001 state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0f:53:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9214 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0f:53:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```